# Error :enoent , rename 'somelocation\appshell.gyp.txt'

Tags: node.js, npm, adobe-brackets

I am trying to create an insallter from cmd (nodejs) i am getting the following error

> Error :enoent , rename 'somelocation\appshell.gyp.txt

Just after executing `grunt install --force`

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENOENT may mean that you have no permissions to read/write to file/directory.

Or file/directory does not exists at all. (check your path)

Comment: hi , thank i got it . but can you help me out . this is my current command                                                               spawn(["cmd.exe /c ant.bat -f brackets-win-install-build.xml"], { cwd: resolve("installer/win"), env: getBracketsEnv() })  in which my grunt shell is not able to locate cmd.exe .   When i give the full path of cmd.exe its working for me . but this is not generic solution can you help me out . how can Grunt shell get the full path automatically..... thanks a  lot in advanced.

Comment: Use `child_process.exec` to execute cmd.exe command. `exec` is already within cmd, so type your stuff after it.
And use ranking system to accept/rate answers as well.